# dummy row in tablesorter pagination

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

i am integration table sorter with pager widget , i have some information block rows in between the table row, i don't want to use the grouping widget. let say i have table with row having class "`myinfo`", this my info need to excluded from table sorter pager count and from total rows

```
<table id="archived">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>period</th>
            <th>period1</th>
            <th>Reason</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="myinfo">
            <td>Today</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>New</td>
            <td>new 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>New</td>
            <td>new 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>New</td>
            <td>new 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="myinfo">
            <td>Next week</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>New</td>
            <td>dummy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>New</td>
            <td>dummy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>New</td>
            <td>dummy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>New</td>
            <td>dummy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="myinfo">
            <td>Last week</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>New</td>
            <td>work</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>New</td>
            <td>work</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>New</td>
            <td>work</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="pager" class="pager paginator" style="text-align: left;padding-top:5px;"> <span class="pagedisplay"></span>&nbsp; <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="/s.gif" class="prev" alt="Previous" title="Previous"></img></a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/791twctz/

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is include a tbody with the class name "tablesorter-infoOnly" - set by the [`cssInfoBlock` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#cssinfoblock) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/4mVfu/4178/)) - either before or after the pager block; the pager knows to ignore these tbodies.

```
<tbody class="tablesorter-infoOnly">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">Extra Information Row</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- add more than one row, if desired -->
</tbody>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ,  this work only with one row ,please look at my case here http://jsfiddle.net/4mVfu/4181/ , i have multiple info block say 1 to 15 in my table